# Vielen Dank für Ihr Verständnis und (Ihre) Unterstützung?

Tags: gender, possessive, redundancy

Ist es grammatikalisch und stilistisch korrekt, in so einem Satz den Possessivartikel wegzulassen, auch wenn es sich hier um Nomen mit verschiedenen Geschlechtern handelt?

Also:
*Vielen Dank für Ihr Verständnis und Unterstützung*
oder
*Vielen Dank für Ihr Verständnis und **Ihre** Unterstützung*
?

Comment: @guidot Solche Belehrungen sollten wenigstens korrekt sein (wenn sie überhaupt nötig sind). Die Duden-Grammatik benutzt den Begriff *possessives Artikelwort* (oder *Possessivartikel*, https://www.duden.de/Fachausdr%C3%BCcke-Buchstabe-P#Possessivartikel), das IDS *Possessiv-Artikel* (https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/194), eine bekannte Übungsgrammatik *Possessivartikel* (https://shop.hueber.de/media/hueber_dateien/Internet_Inhaltsverz/Red7/9783193072559_Inhalt.pdf), etc.

Answer (score 3):

> <strike>Vielen Dank für Ihr Verständnis und Unterstützung.</strike>

Nein, das ist falsch, und es bringt auch jeden Muttersprachler zum Stutzen. Als ob da irgendwo ein Wort fehlt.

> Vielen Dank für Ihr Verständnis und (für) Ihre Unterstützung.

So wird's gemacht.

> Vielen Dank für Ihr Verständnis und (für) die Unterstützung.

So ginge es auch.

Es geht im Übrigen nicht um das Geschlecht des Substantivs, sondern lediglich darum, dass man nur gleiche Teile eines Satzes auslassen kann.

> Sie haben mir mit Ihrem Verständnis und ((mit) Ihrem) Rat geholfen.

- das Verständis, der Rat

Comment: »Als ob« ein Wort fehlt?

Comment: @DonHolgo: Als ob ein Wort fehlt**e**.

Comment: @bakunin: Aber wenn doch tatsächlich ein Wort fehlt, stutzt man nicht, »als ob«, sondern _weil_ das so ist, oder?

Comment: @DonHolgo: "*Als ob* ein Wort fehlte" aber "*Weil* ein Wort fehlt". "Als ob" verlangt Konjunktiv, "weil" den Indikativ. Man kann stutzen *als ob* ein Wort fehlte, egal, ob man damit im Recht ist (weil tatsächlich ein Wort fehlt) oder nicht.

Comment: @DonHolgo: das "als ob" bedeutet hier: "in derselben Art und Weise wie".